# Chrome: Attaching nacl-gdb to packaged application loaded as an unpacked extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gdb, google-nativeclient

I have built a simple NaCl application. For running the application I use technique 2 described in Nacl Developer's guide, which means that instead of running a local server I load my application as unpacked extension to chrome. The application runs fine so far.

Now I want to experiment with nacl-gdb and attach my application to it at startup.
In the NaCl Developer's guide there are only instructions on how to attach nacl-gdb on an application that is run with local server(technique 1). I made a search to the internet and I ended up with the following approach in order to attach nacl-gdb for an application that is being ran with technique 2:

1. I enabled "Native Client GDB-based debugging" flag of Chrome.
2. I started chrome from a terminal like this: ./chrome "--nacl-gdb=gnome-terminal --
   /media/sdb1/leonidasbo/AncientRoot/nacl_sdk/pepper_27/toolchain/linux_x86_glibc/bin/x86_64-nacl-gdb"
3. When Chrome launched, I navigated to my application.

With this approach, Chrome automatically started nacl-gdb when I opened my application.
However nacl-gdb tried to attach but with no success. The output was the following:

*This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-nacl".
Reading symbols from /opt/google/chrome/nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Don't know how to attach.  Try "help target".
(gdb)*

It seems that gdb cannot attach to my application. I tried executing "target exec /path/to/my.nexe", but nothing changed.
Am I missing something here? Is there any other way to debug applications loaded as unpacked extensions with nacl-gdb?

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 and I am using pepper_27 of nacl_sdk. Chrome version is 27.0.1453.93.

Thanks

Comment: I got the exact same problem with a freshly built Chrome / NaCl SDK with Pepper 29. No solution yet.

Comment: Are you using [this guide](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/how-tos/debuggingtips/debugging-with-nacl64-gdb/getting-started-with-x86-64-nacl-gdb)? I was too, but it turns out it's out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you were using [this guide](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/how-tos/debuggingtips/debugging-with-nacl64-gdb/getting-started-with-x86-64-nacl-gdb), which I was using earlier as well. It is out of date. **[These are the real instructions](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/debugging#gdb)**. It seems that the way you attach the debugger has completely changed, and it is no longer possible to use `--nacl-gdb` (that is [planned for removal](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171963)). You must manually attach the debugger by following these steps.

The full guide is **[here](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/debugging#gdb)**, but I'll summarize:

1. Launch Chrome with `chrome --enable-nacl --enable-nacl-debug --no-sandbox --disable-hang-monitor`.
2. Run `<NACL_SDK_ROOT>/toolchain/win_x86_newlib/bin/x86_64-nacl-gdb` (with no arguments).
3. Enter these commands into the gdb prompt:

   - `(gdb) nacl-manifest <path-to-your-.nmf-file>`
   - `(gdb) nacl-irt <CHROME-DIR>/nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe`
   - `(gdb) target remote localhost:4014`

Now you can use gdb as normal. (If you just want to run the application until it crashes, start by typing `continue`.)

Comment: This guide is up-to-date but doesn't include instructions for an application that is being loaded as an unpacked extension. For example the step at third bullet((gdb) target remote localhost:4014) is not applicable because I do not run any server for loading my app.

Comment: It does work for packaged apps (in fact I was using it for one). The guide I linked to uses two localhost addresses: the 4014 one and another; I edited the other one out because it doesn't apply to packaged apps. localhost:4014 is the address of the GDB server to connect the GDB client to. It runs automatically with --enable-nacl-debug.